# The enigma of the S or N word

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay

Hi there puzzling community, i wanted to say hello and have something good to share for my first post, but unfortunately i have bad news. My distant cousin, who was very rich, fell ill and died.

To our surprise he did not leave a testament. Instead, he left a big fortune inside a locked chamber in his house, with a password. The only thing we know is that the password has 9 letters. I remember it well having a big round table in which the whole family sat to eat tea and pastries, a sister of mine used the cam a lot to record those precious moments. He was also a big fan of Sherlock Holmes novels, so that is why i think he left this note on his funeral, like an unsolved mystery.

> N is not true.

Knowing my cousin, he surely gave me the password to open the chamber, but i cannot figure it out.

Can you help me to figure it out? It would be legendary :)

Thanks!

PD: I am the author of this :)

Comment: Ill edit and give more information about it. Thanks :)

Comment: Edited the text. I think that giving away the number of letters of the password should make this clearer. Thanks for your advice :D

Comment: Be warned that finding the password of your cousin's chamber doesn't give you any legal right on his inheritance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A wild guess, but a plausible one.

> The title speaks about the "S or N word".

> If N is not true, N is not the right word.  The right word is the "S word".

> "S word" ... like "sword".

> The round table suggests the cousin is also fan of the Knights of the Round Table.

> These two pieces of information point to "Excalibur".

PS:

> Cap noted there is a play of words with "cam a lot".

> If you google, there is a book called "Sherlock Holmes and the Round Table Adventure".  But it is not by Conan Doyle, so not sure it is related.

Comment: Nice. There is also rot13(pnz n ybg)

Comment: Good find! I was wondering about that detail in the story.

Comment: Thats It! Im glad you took all the wordplay. Very nice job.

Comment: You do yourself an injustice by describing this as 'a wild guess' - you've spotted clues in the text and narrowed down the options based on information you've discovered in the puzzle. This answer is of a much higher quality than the usual ones that get posted on this site as self-described 'wild guesses'...

Comment: Thank you.  I qualified it a "wild guess" because there were too many story elements that I didn't use.  I thought this is not the complete solution.  It is only later that these elements appeared to confirm the story.  But OK, it wasn't that "wild" after all.